# incrementing multiple IP addresses in VIM

Tags: vim, replace, increment

I would like to edit my hosts file to match my current IPs, I could do it in Python or AWK, but I was wondering if there is a way in VIM...

let's see what I mean, my hosts looks like that:

```
192.168.11.172    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.173    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.225    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

Now, I want to increment every IP by 32 so the end result would be:

```
192.168.11.202    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.203    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.257    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

If I put my cursor on the right IP, and type

> 30 and CTRL+A

it does what I want.

The only problem, I have about 300 hosts ... and I need to do it once every 3 months ...
Although I could do it in Python, seeing the file in vim **feels** safer, because I don't need to run a script and then control the result after that.

The following changes only the first line:

```
let i=172 | g/172/s//\=i+30/
```

I want to repeat this in a loop for different IP ranges being able to say how many times i should be incremented, is there a "trick" that does that?

Thanks in advance for the efforts, 
Oz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
:let i=30 | %s/^\(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\)\(\d*\)/\=submatch(1).(submatch(2)+i)
```

`\(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\)` (retrieved by `submatch(1)`) matches the IP first three  numbers and dots (eg `192.168.11.`) and `\(\d*\)` (retrieved by `submatch(2)`) matches the IP last number.

I think this is a better way to control it:

```
:let i=30 | %s/^\(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\)\(\d*\)/\=submatch(1).(submatch(2)+i)/gc
```

Comment: `\1` and `\2` would be the same as `submatch(1)` and `submatch(2)`, no?

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, but using `\=` and `submatch` I can do the sum with `i`

Comment: @dusan, what does submatch(1) and submatch(2) stand for?

Comment: @Oz123, when you use `\(...\)`, the matched string inside it could be referenced later by `submatch`. In dusan's example, there are 2 of them, one matching the first 3 numbers (and 3 dots) of IP and the second matching the fourth number.

Comment: @Shahbaz, thanks I see. At the beginning dusan's answer looked like chineese. But now I see what he did, he matched the first 3 bytes, and then the last byte, and finally told vim to increment by 30 the last byte. VIM is damn expressive!

Comment: @Oz123, once you start working with ViM, all other editors seem stupid. Admittedly though, a lot of functionalities in ViM are not its own innovations. For example the syntax above is quite widely used with `sed`, `grep` and many other unixy tools.

Comment: @Shahbaz, that is why I like working with it. Like I said, this would not be hard writing in Python (my favorite language) or do in AWK. But sometimes the ability to do stuff with VIM in Unixy way is a great gift.

Answer (score 3):

I am certainly not a vim expert (yet), but this is how I would do it (`[]` shows cursor position)

```
192.168.11.[1]72    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.173    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.225    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

Press `qa` (start a macro with name a). Do your modification (for example `30 CTRL-A`). The cursor should now be here:

```
192.168.11.20[2]    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.173    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.225    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

Press `b` to go the beginning of the word:

```
192.168.11.[2]02    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.173    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.225    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

Press `j` (or down arrow) to go to the start of next number to be changed:

```
192.168.11.202    blazer blazer.mydomain
192.168.11.[1]73    faster faster.mydomain
...
192.168.11.225    schurtig schurtig.mydomain
```

Press `q` to terminate macro definition.

Now that you have 53 IPs left, you just need to repeat the macro 53 times: `53@a`

Comment: Thanks shabaz, that's is a way also... But I was thinking more on vim scripting with let i=172 and then do the changing part 53 times... But I like this solution too. Let's see what comes next :-)

Comment: @Oz123, I haven't learned ViM scripting yet. Too much to learn too little time...

Comment: @Shabaz, that's no problem at all. Your answer is still appreciated. Believe it or not, I still learned from it, how to do macros, so you get an upvote.

Comment: @Oz123, macros are very useful. They can get quite tricky though. For example, you should refrain from using autocomplete or other things that may put things in a way that you don't expect. Just as a bonus, you should know that even the `:w` and other commands can be saved in the macro. So for example if you have opened many files (say `vim *.c`), you can save a macro like this `qa ... :w :bn q` and you update, save and switch to the next file!

Answer (score 3):

One can use the following substitution command.

```
:%s/\(\d\+\.\)\{3}\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+30/g
```

Comment: Ah. I had exactly the same simplification worked out. Well, I'd use verymagic with that: `let i=30 | %s/\v(\d+\.){3}\zs\d+/\=submatch(0)+i/g`